# Crystaldecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.dll not found on client computer

Tags: visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, crystal-reports

I wrote a .NET DLL that uses a `ReportViewer` in VS2010. On the development computer, it works well. However, when I install the program on a client, I get the error message that `Crystaldecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.dll` is not found.

I installed both the .NET 4 framework and the 32-bit runtime MSI that SAP provides as a free download.

What else do I need to do to get this to work?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Did you download the runtime from the website below?
http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824

Maybe on the project setting -> reference, you can try to set to copy the dll to local and see if it works...

Comment: The runtime.msi I used must have been the wrong one or corrupt. After redownloading all was fine.